# use angular $http with django urlpatterns to get a json file

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, angularjs

what I am trying to do is send a $http GET request to a django url pattern and return a .json file. Can I use urlpatterns to return a file instead of a view?

is this even possible?

currently  form/data is returning 500

testModule.js

```
angular.module('mod1', ['mod2'])

.controller('resorcesCtrl', ['mod2Factory',
     function(mod2Factory) {
        mod2Factory.getJSON();
     }
]);


angular.module('mod2', [])
   .factory('mod2Factory', [ '$http',
      function($http) {

        var getJSON = function() {
           return $http({
           url: "/form/data",
           method: "GET"
        })
      }

      return {
         getJSON:getJSON
      }; 
    }
  ])
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^form/data', 'myApp.views.getJSON', name='getJSON'),
```

views.py

```
def getJSON(request):
    context = {
        "json": json
    }
    return render(request, '', context)
```

Comment: What is the content of your 500 error? Can you put it here with the stacktrace? Which version of Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Django 1.7, there is a new response object called [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects).

Your view can be as simple as:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def getJSON(request):
    # context is a Python dict.
    context = {
        "key": "value",
        "other_key": 365,
    }
    return JsonResponse(context)
```

The `context` must be a valid JSON serializable object. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) for more detail about `JsonResponse`. If you have any trouble with serialization, you can pass your own encoder to `JsonResponse` to handle custom data types, [read more](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats-json).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer use a function like that

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse

def json_responder(**kwargs):
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(kwargs), content_type="application/json")

def yourview(request):
    return json_responder(type='error', msg='a message")
```

and that can be used on every django version